# how to double the first word in a line that have 3 words using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file called `test` that have:

```
1 2 3
2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20
```

I want to get the lines that have 3 words in them, and then print them, while the first word is duplicated.

I cant use pipeline, and I can use >| to put it in a tmp file and read from it.

so the output in this case is:

```
1 1 2 3
8 8 9 10
18 18 19 20
```

I understand more or less what regular expr I need, but the rest im struggling, could someone please help :?

this is what I did:

```
sed 's/'^[^ ]*[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]+[^ ]+[ ]*$'/&&/1/ test
```

I know this is not the solution but please help me understand :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this,

```
$ sed -nr 's/^([^ ]+) +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+$/\1 &/p' file
1 1 2 3
8 8 9 10
18 18 19 20
```

From `man sed`

```
-n, --quiet, --silent
             suppress automatic printing of pattern space
p      Print the current pattern space.
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start. `(..)` called capturing group, which is used to capture characters. Later you could refer those captured characters by back-referencing it's index number. `([^ ]+)` Captures any character but not of a space one or more times. `+` repeats the previous token one or more times. `$` asserts that we are at the line end.

**OR**

```
$ sed -n 's/^\([^[:blank:]]\+\)\([[:blank:]]\+\)[^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+[^[:blank:]]\+$/\1\2&/p' file
1 1 2 3
8 8 9 10
18 18 19 20
```

`[^[:blank:]]\+` Matches one or more non-space characters. `[[:blank:]]\+` matches one or more space characters. `&` in the replacement part will print all the matched characters.

Comment: thank!! just had to cover the case that i have spaces in the end of a line, so i added [ ]*$

Comment: could you please add some basic explanation to your first solution? $ sed -nr 's/^([^ ]+) +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+$/\1 &/p' file

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is not the tool of choice for space-delimited data. Since there are already answers that use `sed` here are some alternatives:

**awk**

```
awk 'NF==3 { print $1, $1, $2, $3 }' < test
```

**Plain POSIX shell**

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS=' ' read -r a b c d; do
    if [ ! -z "$a" -a ! -z "$b" -a ! -z "$c" -a -z "$d" ]; then
        echo "$a $a $b $c";
    fi
 done < test
```

Comment: but i need sed, no awk

Comment: @nickshmick Can you use plain bash?

Comment: `awk 'NF==3&&$1=$1" "$1'`

Comment: @TheChef Nice. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @nwk OP said they don't want awk :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` solution that takes only word characters:

```
$ sed -n "s/^\(\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\) [a-zA-Z0-9]\+ [a-zA-Z0-9]\+$\)/\2 \1/p" test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Posix
sed '/^\([^ ]\{1,\}\)\( [^ ]\{1,\}\)\{2\}$/ !d;s//\1 &/' YourFile

# GNU
sed '/^([^ ]+)( [^ ]+){2}$/ !d;s//\1 &/' YourFile
```

assuming space are only 1 space char (if not, just change space matching with `[[:space:]]\{1,\}`

Answer (score 0):

**To simply duplicate first word:**

```
sed 's/[^ ]\+ /&&/' input-file
```

**To require three words:**

```
sed 's/\b//5; T; s/[^ ]\+ /&&/' input-file
```

- try to substitute the 5th word boundary (would be start of third word)
- if that fails, `T` branch to next line of input and do nothing
- otherwise `s/[^ ]\+/&&/` duplicate the first word.

**Finally, to delete the lines with fewer than three words as well:**

```
sed 's/\b//5; Td; s/[^ ]\+ /&&/; t; :d d' input-file
```

- `Td` to branch to label `:d` and `d` delete if there are 5 word boundaries
- `t` to not delete after lines with more words

All are GNU sed... may be required for both `\+` and `s///5` syntax.